# Cannot gather stats and Invalid template file after installing Porto theme

Tags: file-permissions, docker, porto-theme, magento-cloud, invalid-template

After [setting up Magento 2 in developer mode](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-mode-developer.html), I am getting a couple of errors:

```
[2021-04-19 21:39:09] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2021-04-19 21:39:09] report.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /app/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /app/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /app/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:95)"} []
[2021-04-19 21:39:10] report.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'owl_list.phtml' in module: 'Smartwave_Filterproducts' block's name: 'home\featuredlist_0' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\ValidatorException(code: 0): Invalid template file: 'owl_list.phtml' in module: 'Smartwave_Filterproducts' block's name: 'home\\featuredlist_0' at /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:280)"} []
[2021-04-19 21:39:10] report.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'grid.phtml' in module: 'Smartwave_Filterproducts' block's name: 'home\featuredlist_1' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\ValidatorException(code: 0): Invalid template file: 'grid.phtml' in module: 'Smartwave_Filterproducts' block's name: 'home\\featuredlist_1' at /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:280)"} []
```

The file permissions for mixins.js are `-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 7375 Apr 19 17:01 mixins.js`

owl_list.phtml and grid.phtml are both located in `/app/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Filterproducts/templates/`

I followed the Magento 2 documentation to install Magento in docker. Then, in an attempt to follow the [Porto docs](https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/documentation/), I copied the Porto theme files, the theme patch for Magento 2.2.x, theme patch for Magento 2.3.x, and the theme patch for Magento 2.4.1.

Any help on resolving the above errors would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I missed one small, but important step when installing the porto theme

> Select Smartwave Porto theme. in Stores > Configuration > General >
> Design > Design Theme > Design Theme for Magento 2.0.x version
>
> select Smartwave Porto theme in Content > Design > Configuration page
> for Magento 2.1.x or 2.2.x version You can select Smartwave Porto RTL
> theme, if you want to build a RTL site.

https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

As per the error Magento is not able to locate following templates

`Invalid template file: 'owl_list.phtml'`
`Invalid template file: 'grid.phtml'`

in `Smartwave_Filterproducts` module. Check whether this templates exists in module or not.

If these templates are missing then you can create a ticket in porto support for it.